# can't run meteor tests using practicalmeteor:mocha - file structure issue

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, meteor, mocha.js

I am developing a simple web application in Meteor JS.
I want to run tests using practicalmeteor:mocha
so I run

```
 meteor add practicalmeteor:mocha
```

and I can start the meteor app in the test mode correctly having this

[running in test mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOiwN.png)

The problem is I'm trying to add tests and run it but I don't know where to put it.

I created a folder in the root of the project named "tests" and put a file  named test.tests.js, the file contents is:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Random } from 'meteor/random';
import { assert } from 'meteor/practicalmeteor:chai';


 describe('movie_db',function({

    it('can view only existing movies', () => {
        // Find the internal implementamtion of the task method so we can
        // test it in isolation
        const result = movies.find({name: "adsgfdfhggfsd"}).count();

        // Verify that the method does what we expected
        assert.equal(result, 0);
    });

 }));
```

but nothing happens in the page with test results, I still have 0 pass and 0 failed (As if there's no any test written).

So I need to know what should I do to run these tests.

============== Edit ===========================

it worked when I put the test in the server or the client folders.
the client tests in the client folder and the server tests in the server folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation isn't clear about this, but basically when you are testing with practicalmeteor:mocha, you want your tests saved as .tests.js but not in a /tests folder.

If they are in a /tests folder they won't be seen. Hope that helps

Comment: It worked when I put the client tests into the client folder and the server tests into the test folder.

the test file should be ended with .tests.js as you mentioned.

Thanks :)